# R - shapiro-wilk test - loop

Tags: r, loops

I would like to apply a shapiro-wilk test to a bunch of data using a for loop and save the p-values in a matrix called "shapiro.mat_mining". 
here's what i have tried without sucsess,

```
shapiro.mat_mining=matrix(c("Zr","Sr","Rb","Zn","Cu","Fe","Mn","V","Ti","Sc","Ca","K","S","Ba","Cs",numeric(15)),nrow=(2),byrow=TRUE)


#Shapiro-wilk
for (ii in c("Zr","Sr","Rb","Zn","Cu","Fe","Mn","V","Ti","Sc","Ca","K","S","Ba","Cs")){
  shapiro.mat_mining[2,ii]=shapiro.test(VI9A_mining[,ii])$p.value

}
```

"Zr","Sr",.. are all vectors. 
VI9A_mining is a matrix containing the vectors Zr, Sr,...

When i run this, the error message is :

```
"Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 2, ii, value = 0.219114698955686) : 
  no 'dimnames' attribute for array"
```

This script : "`SW_mining_zr=shapiro.test(VI9A_mining[,1])$p.value`" works. But i would like to do it through the loop.

Comment: First, you cannot mix strings and numerics in a matrix, use either separate matrices (or rather a numeric vector for p-values) or e.g. a `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks!
seems better, but still doesn't run. 

shapiro.pval_mining=c(numeric(15))


#Shapiro-wilk
for (ii in c("Zr","Sr","Rb","Zn","Cu","Fe","Mn","V","Ti","Sc","Ca","K","S","Ba","Cs")){
  shapiro.pval_mining[ii]=shapiro.test(VI9A_mining[,ii])$p.value
 
}

now the error message is :"Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE"

any idea?

Comment: 1. You don't need `c()` with `numeric()`. 2. Yes, something expected to be a numeric is not: `is.numeric(x) is not TRUE`, try `shapiro.pval_mining['Zr']` and ` shapiro.pval_mining[1]`.